# Flutter Dart Map update multiple Values for one Key

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart, key

How to update multiple value in one key?

```
Map<DateTime, List> _event;
```

```
_event.update(day, (contents) => contents..add(listNum),
          ifAbsent: () => [listNum]); //type Int
_event.update(day, (contents) => contents..add(title),
          ifAbsent: () => [title]); //type String
_event.update(day, (contents) => contents..add(details),
          ifAbsent: () => [details]); //type String
```

I tried it by upper code, but it generate only 3 multiple maps, not value(elements in List)

is there any way to updates multiple Value by simple way?

thanks.

Comment: `Map<int, List> m = {};
m.update(0, (l) => l..add('foo'), ifAbsent: () => ['foo']);
print(m);
m.update(0, (l) => l..add('bar'), ifAbsent: () => ['bar']); print(m);` - what do you see in the logs when you run it?

Comment: {0: [foo]}
{0: [foo, bar]}

Comment: so the key `0` is updated, isnt it?

Comment: yeah, it was list. my misunderstood :(

Comment: sure, your welcome